# react-beautiful-dnd drag clone from a list

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm trying to achieve something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/40p81qy7v0?file=/index.js
It works well in the editor from the sandbox, but when I'm running the code on my computer it doesn't work as in the example.
When dragging something the next element underneath disappears.
Does anybody have any idea of how can I achieve this cloning effect?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I forked this project to my github and cloned it in my machine, and everything works fine. I do think it's about the version of the package "react-beautiful-dnd" you are using. Try to change the version of this package to 8.0.5.

Here my repository, I think that if you change it as you did in codesandbox you will achieve your goal:
https://github.com/yuugodev/dragdrop2